# AWS DynamoDB persistent connection

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Given AWS Lambda on NodeJS 6-th version, which performs very simple test-purposes CRUD interaction with DynamoDB table. Measured performance is extremely slow, independent to selected Lambda RAM memory or RCU/WCU units for Dynamodb.

There was performed benchmark, and results are unsatisfied. Event MySQL database in micro container has performance, which is better compare to DynamoDB with some times.

```
Update operations        1000            10000             20000            100000

RCU=1000/WCU=1000      104708 ms       176109 ms         276689 ms         N/A >5min
                        942 MB          707 MB            896 MB         

RCU=2000/WCU=2000      45953 ms        167686 ms         245937 ms         N/A >5min
                        646 MB          829 MB            896 MB       

RCU=3000/WCU=3000      74205 ms        151072 ms         253800 ms         N/A >5min
                        657 MB          840 MB            854 MB      

RCU=4000/WCU=4000      76636 ms        175258 ms         257238 ms         N/A >5min
                        896 MB          896 MB            896 MB
```

After fast research reason of such behavior was found: DynamoDB performs new HTTP(S) request on each CRUD operation! (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/lib/http/node.js#L25) It's extremely slow, event in TLS connection, which has relatively big establishment time, including key exchanges. Also, it's extremely big overhead for HTTP headers, which some times bigger than CRUD payload.

So **question**: is there available method to communicate with DynamoDB in persistent connection in NodeJS Labmda? Batch operations is not apropriate solution, since they does not support UPDATE operations.

Comment: Were you able to improve the performance using any other method? I am stuck in a similar situation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that AWS Node SDK supports Keep-alive by default.
We need to set AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED environment variable to 1.

Please refer:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-reusing-connections.html

Answer (score 0):

By design, DynamoDB is a web service. You can't have persistent connection to the database like RDBMS or any other database.

> DynamoDB is a web service, and interactions with it are stateless.
>   Applications do not need to maintain persistent network connections.
>   Instead, interaction with DynamoDB occurs using HTTP(S) requests and
>   responses.

[Dynamodb connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.Accessing.html)

**Workaround Solution:-**

If the updates are not related, you can asynchronously update the item to improve performance. However, you may need to think about how you would like to handle errors in this case.

The below code doesn't have callback on `update`. So, it calls the update operation and doesn't wait for its response.

```
requestObj = docClient.update(params);
requestObj.send();
```

Comment: Persistent *logical* connections are of course not possible over HTTP... but doesn't the SDK at least use HTTP keep-alive?  That would avoid a large amount of unnecessary TLS negotiation overhead.  Looking at the source code, I don't see it, and that seems like a significant design oversight, if true, but also something that could be fixed.  Do you see keep-alives being used?

Comment: What about this?  It seems to imply socket reuse is possible, but doesn't seem to mention default behavior.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-configuring-maxsockets.html... Or it may be saying that the default is 50.  Not sure what is being said here.

Comment: Yes, if be more accurate, solution like `keep-alive` based is meant. But researching source code and debugging over `aws-sdk` JS library shows, that in fact is does not support `keep-alive` connection. Some answers on AWS Dynamo desk shows, that it should respect `keep-alive` options, but in real world `aws-sdk` just creates new HTTP(S) connections.

Comment: Now only one obvious workaround is seen: provide custom HTTP agent for outgoing connections, and perform manual translate multiple HTTP(S) requests into one HTTP(S) connection sequentially. 
In bad case it's possible to write own AWS API wrapper, but it's very strange, that AWS does not implement that extremely important functionality